# Who to contact for a bird with broken wing in Portugal, Algarve?

Tags: birds, animals, first-aid, portugal

I saw a bird with an injured wing among the rocks on a beach in Portugal (Algarve). The bird has been on the beach since Friday evening, and her wing feathers have completely dropped off by now.

It's quite big (a seagull?) and I'm not at all confident to capture it myself. I also have no idea how to capture it or give it first aid :(

I tried calling GNR, the regular Police, the Maritime Police, and some conservation SOS lines, but they all say they can't pick it up.
The GNR advised me they don't pick up injured animals any more (the rep said "new rules") :(

I feel really bad about leaving the bird to die in such a way (not sure if it can even recover at this point).

Is there anybody I can contact?

(There is one more organisation ICNF that works only on workdays that I plan to call tomorrow.)

Thanks in advance for any advice or help!

**Update Monday, 3 days later:** called like 10 more different numbers and they just keep giving me new numbers to call which don't pick up or give me new numbers... :(

The numbers I've called on the slim chance they are helpful for someone else in the future even though **they did not work for me sadly**:

- 1) SOS Environment Line (SEPNA / GNR) 808 200 520
- 2) The nearest GNR station to allow referrals to the SEPNA team 
  GNR Portimão 282 420 750
- 3) Nearest ICNF Headquarters (on weekdays from 9am to 5pm), ICNF Lagos
  282 402 320
- 4) RIAS Phone 927 659 313
- 5) Rescue centre Olhao 289 700
  210
- 6) Maritime police  282 767 983
- 7) regular police  282 780 240
- 8) local city hall Environment & urban services

Comment: I have no answer for Portugal.  In the US, I would call the nearest wildlife rescue organization.  They might not travel to pick up the gull, but they would have useful advice on how to capture it and transport it and the best place to take it.  I can tell you that you cannot do this alone.  You will need a 2nd person.  Does the bird become agitated when you approach it?  Best not to agitate it.  Can you feed it or give it water?

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Yes, it's a wild bird so it actually tries to hide among the rocks on approach. I have absolutely no equipment to catch it and it seems like I'll just stress it out. Not sure if I should try to give it water or food; it might be beyond help I'm afraid :( except for a merciful dispatch - which I can't do either... Sad thing is it's a crowded beach very close to a populated place

Comment: @ozmichka It looks like you pot a lot of effort into your search, kudos for that! It also means your list is already a good answer to your own question and for attracting potential readers it would be nice if you'd move it to an answer - a question with one answer looks more useful than a question with no answer (well, answer in the question, but how would you know before ;) ).

Comment: Agreed with @imsodin - make the edit a self answer it's a good bit of information!

Comment: @imsodin thanks for the idea! However, it's not really an answer as it did not work :( The bird's gone now, hopefully it died peacefully

Answer (score 6):

The numbers I've called on the slim chance they are helpful for someone else in the future **even though they did not work for me sadly:**

- 1) SOS Environment Line (SEPNA / GNR) 808 200 520
- 2) The nearest GNR
  station to allow referrals to the SEPNA team GNR Portimão 282 420 750
- 3) Nearest ICNF Headquarters (on weekdays from 9am to 5pm), ICNF
  Lagos 282 402 320
- 4) RIAS Phone 927 659 313
- 5) Rescue centre Olhao
  289 700 210
- 6) Maritime police 282 767 983
- 7) regular police 282 780
  240
- 8) local city hall Environment & urban services

Answer (score 5):

The British organisation RSPB is partnering:

> SPEA-BirdLife Portugal, Avenida da Liberdade, No 105 - 2oEsq, 1250-140 Lisboa, Portugal 
>   Telephone: (+351) 21 322 04 03.

As shown [here](https://www.rspb.org.uk/our-work/conservation/projects/portugal-country-programme).

Although sadly it is now too late for action.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Do you know if this organization has teams in Southern Portugal? I see they are based in Lisbon.

Comment: @ozmichka I don't know, I simply found another organisation in Portugal interested in the welfare of birds. SPEA might be interested only in their conservation.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. I'll update here if I find out anything more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar question in the future, RIAS Wildlife Rescue Center seems to be the place to contact in the Algarve - instructions in English here: http://rias-aldeia.blogspot.com/p/en.html?m=1

Comment: Please try to include all relevant information in the answer itself, so that the answer is "complete" in itself - without the reader having to open the link.